# Is there anyone who is really able to get facebook page feed through realtime updates?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I was trying to setup a realtime update for one of my facebook app from a facebook page. I have tried each and every process described in facebook official api docs as well as other developers blogs. But no luck till now. My subscription is successful, I can see it both from api explorer and facebook url. My callback url also works perfectly. But when something new published in my page, I don't get any updates. Hoping anyone will reply who got it really working by him/her self.

Please do not suggest any facebook doc, I have already tried them.